# Count occurrences of elements in a list until a different element appears

Tags: python

Given a list :

```
lst = [1,1,1,5,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3]
```

I want to count the occurrences of each item in the list as they appear in the list so for instance the number `3` in this case will be count two times when `3` is between `5` and `9` it will have a count of `2` and when `3` is after `9` it will have a count of `5`. The resulting list should be the item followed by its count.

```
result = [1,3,5,1,3,2,9,1,3,5]
```

I've tried the following code but it results in a sort of expanded answer.

```
lst = [1,1,1,5,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3]

def myfun(arr):
    for i in arr:
        yield i
        yield arr.count(i)

print(list(myfun(lst)))


[1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 7, 3, 7, 9, 1, 3, 7, 3, 7, 3, 7, 3, 7, 3, 7]
```

Comment: Try `itertools.groupby`. There are several previous questions on the site, although I can't decide on the best duplicate.

Comment: What you are asking for is known as RLE (Run Length Encoding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is good for this. It will group the items by a key and return and iterator with the key, grouper containing items. You can convert the gouper to a list and take it's length:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [1,1,1,5,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3]

def counts(lst):
    for k, v in groupby(lst):
        yield k
        yield len(list(v))

list(counts(lst))
# [1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 9, 1, 3, 5]
```

You can do it as a one-liner with `chain` too:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

lst = [1,1,1,5,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3]

list(chain.from_iterable((k, len(list(v))) for k, v in groupby(lst)))
# [1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 9, 1, 3, 5]
```

If, for some reason, you want to do this the hard way, you need to keep track of the current count and the current thing you are counting and append when that thing changes:

```
lst = [1,1,1,5,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3]

def makeCounts(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0: 
        return lst
    res = []
    # take first element
    cur = lst[0]
    count = 1

    for n in lst[1:]:
        if n == cur:
            # same item — increase count
            count += 1
        else:
            # new item — reset count and save previous
            res.extend([cur, count])
            count = 1
            cur = n

    # don't forget last item
    res.extend([cur, count])

    return res

makeCounts(lst)
# [1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 9, 1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: yes I wanted to do the hard way in order to learn. thanks a lot

Comment: why the last item gets out of the loop in the hard way?

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini because you only save items when `n != cur`. In the case of the last group, this doesn't happen and you have left over items that need to be added to the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 3, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
count = 0
result = []


def myfun(idx, arr):
    global count
    if idx < len(arr):
        if idx + 1 < len(arr) and (arr[idx + 1] - arr[idx]) == 0:
            count += 1
            myfun(idx + 1, arr)
        else:
            result.append(arr[idx])
            count += 1
            result.append(count)
            count = 0
            myfun(idx + 1, arr)


myfun(0, lst)
print(result)
#[1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 9, 1, 3, 5]
```